# Is it is possible to change the targeted app store after the app is released?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Recently I have released my app into the US AppStore. Now I Planed for a world wide release. So I need to change the AppStore and release my app world wide. But I don't know how to change the AppStore after release my app. I searched for an answer, but my bad I didn't get anything helpful. IS it is possible to edit the targeted AppStore after complete release process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the regions your application is available in with iTunes Connect.

Todo so follow these simple steps:

- Login to https://itunesconnect.apple.com
- Click "Manager your Applications"
- Select your application
- Click "Rights and Pricing" (before you select the specific version)
- Just below the pricing tier options you change regions

I hope this helped.